# How to push DiffableDataSourceSnapshot update inside main thread?

Tags: uitableview, queue, diffabledatasource

Im new to UITableViewDiffableDataSource,
When I prepare the DiffableDataSourceSnapshot and apply? I can see that update is triggering from `Dispatch queue: com.apple.uikit.datasource.diffing` Im expecting all UI operations has to be in the `main-thread`, does anyone having idea on how to push it in the main thread?